# Stacked ListViews, optimal height distribution

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'd need a page with two `ListViews` stacked vertically. For starters, both should be half the height of the page (for instance, when they're empty or only has a small number of items, not needing scrolling). However, as item counts start to increase, the two should be sized (nearly) optimally: if, for instance, the top list has only one item and the bottom list has many, the top should shrink to minimum and the bottom should show as much as possible.

`FlexLayout` is just one of the attempts:

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Column" Wrap="NoWrap">
  <ListView FlexLayout.Grow="1" ... />
  <ListView FlexLayout.Grow="1" ... />
</FlexLayout>
```

After checking many available options (flex layouts, grids, etc), it seems to me that this cannot be solved without a custom layout. Unless I missed something; what would be really nice...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this format once.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinations>
    <RowDefination Height = "Auto"/>   
    <RowDefination Height = "*"/>   
 </Grid.RowDefinations> 

<ListView Grid.RowDefination = "0">

     // required code for your fist listview

   </ListView>
   <ListView Grid.RowDefination = "1">

     // required code for your second listview

   </ListView>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: No chance, unfortunately. If `Auto`, it will occupy the whole vertical space (no matter what the `VerticalOptions` are). If I use star values, those proportions will be observed and my main goal would be to make varying proportions according to contents